# Gate Driver Output Wiring (TC4431)

Tags: gate-driving

I don't know how to how to properly wire the two outputs of the driver IC TC4431 to the MOSFET gate.

In the datasheet, there's a test circuit diagram (@page7, FIG4-1), should I connect the outputs together to the gate pin?
Since resistors might be needed to fine tune Turn-On and Turn-Off timings on the actual PCB (as mentioned in page 6), I need to consider placing spaceholder pinouts (If not needed I'll populate with 0 Ω resistors). Which is the right wiring or should the resistors be pull-up pull-down as it's common on MOSFET gates (and left unpopulated if not needed)?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKRGDY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Datasheet: [TC4431](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21424d.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application diagram suggests the pins can be shorted together if need be.

[image]

Diodes are certainly not required.

Separate resistors may be desired for changing rise/fall times independently, or perhaps for reducing shoot-through current.[1]

If equal resistors would be used, the outputs can be shorted together and a single resistor used instead.

---

[1] Shoot-through is not documented on this type.  At best, Fig.2-1 hints at it, but the no-load consumption could be due to internal paths as well as output shoot-through per se.  And though 4.7µF is indicated (a rather large bypass capacitor, especially in relation to the ~nF typical loads shown), it might simply have been chosen out of habit rather than need.  More characterization is needed to determine if shoot-through can be managed this way.

Whatever the case, shoot-through (both outputs being active, pulling up and down, simultaneously) is only a concern with respect to supply current and device dissipation, not basic device operation and function.  Maybe EMI.  The possibility would simply be this: even if one intends to use equal up and down resistors, supply current may be slightly lower with independent resistors, rather than shorting the pins together and using one resistor.